# Update the first row in sql server table if a condition is met

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with the following rows.

**tblPictures**

- picID
- picName
- galleryID
- isActive

I want to run a query to select for example all the pictures with `galleryID=3` and `isActive=1`

If there are no pictures in this select with the isActive row being 1 (in other words, query returns no results) I want to make the first picture's `isActive=1` with the `galleryID=3`

Can anyone guide me on this?

Comment: You need to tell us how to define "first." SQL Server considers a table an unordered set of rows; you need to give it criteria (e.g. earliest value in a given datetime column) so that it can reliably and repeatedly use the same method to update the row you call "first."

Comment: what do you mean by the first row?  sorted by primary index or what?

Comment: Ok I apologise for not being clear.. I am updating my question now..

Comment: Ok, question is updated.. hope it is ok..

Comment: Your edit still gives no indication of what you consider the "first row". As @AaronBertrand explained, there is no "first row" unless you have a criteria that makes it so (like a date or time stamp, or an id that changes for each row, etc.). IOW, if you have five pictures where `galleryID  = 3`, which one of those five rows is "first"?

Comment: ok, if there is no records with isActive=1 then I want to SELECT * FROM tblPhotos WHERE galleryID=3.. If for example, this query returns 5 results, I want to get the first result and make its isActive=1

Comment: And what do you want if there *are* rows with isActive = 1? No word problems, please; post sample data and desired results in each case.

Comment: if there are rows with isActive=1, then it should do nothing. I am not being able to post sample code, as I can't figure out the logic to do this - hence no code.. that is why I need your help..

Comment: Sample data and desired results are not code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you go.  Basically, it checks to see if there are any Active records in that set, and if not, updates the first one (determined by the picID). You can stick it in a stored procedure or function if you like, or just run the script and change the gallery ID manually.

```
DECLARE @Count INT,
@GalleryID INT

SET @GalleryID = 3

SELECT @Count = COUNT(*)
FROM tblPictures
WHERE galleryID=@GalleryID and isActive=1

IF @Count = 0
BEGIN

UPDATE tblPictures
SET isActive = 1
WHERE picID = (
    SELECT TOP 1 picID 
    FROM tblPictures 
    WHERE galleryID = @GalleryID 
    ORDER BY picID
    )

END
```

MOAR CODE

This should update the first picture (by picID) in any gallery without an active picture:

```
UPDATE tblPictures
SET isActive = 1
WHERE picID IN (
    SELECT picID 
    FROM (
        SELECT galleryID, MIN(picID) AS 'picID'
        FROM tblPictures AS p
        JOIN (
            SELECT galleryID 
            FROM tblPictures 
            WHERE isActive = 1
            ) AS s ON p.galleryID <> s.galleryID
        GROUP BY galleryID
        )
    )
```

The innermost subquery finds the galleries that DO have active pictures.  The next step up finds the galleryIDs excluding the ones that have pictures.  Then we find the lowest picID for each galleryID and use those to update the table.

Comment: Emin, I added another query that should do the whole table in one shot if you want to take a look.

Comment: It's like you are being poetic tonight :)) thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
declare @tav table

(

gallaryid int,

isactive int

)

insert into @tav 

select

3,0 union all

select

4,0 union all

select

5,1

select * from @tav

update @tav set isactive=1

where gallaryid=3 and isactive=(select top(1)isactive from @tav  order by isactive)

select * from @tav

where gallaryid=3 and isactive=1
```